# MYSQL max connection reset

Tags: mysql, percona

Good day, folks.

I am new to MySQL and we have encountered an issue with our configuration. Initially, we set the max_connections parameter to 4000 in the mysqld.conf file located in the default MySQL directory. To make this setting effective, we restarted MySQL. However, upon checking the value in MySQL CLI, we found that the max_connections value remained at 214, not 4000.

As a workaround, we used the global variables command to set the value to 4000:

**
set global variables max_connection=4000;.
**

This solved our problem at the time.

Later, we experienced another issue where the max_connections value was reset to 214. We investigated this issue and wondered if it might be related to high RAM usage on the server. RAM usage was consistently high, consuming all available resources, and the innodb_buffer_pool_size was set to consume 80% of the RAM.

We need to understand the possible causes of this issue to resolve it effectively.

Comment: If you set it in a conf file, either you did so incorrectly or it is being reset in a different file.  Setting the variable will only last until the server restarts, unless you do set persist

Comment: Another possibility I've seen before is that the conf file also contains another line lower down in the file, setting the `max_connections` to 214. The _last_ line in the file for a given config option takes precedence.